Taylor expansion of scalar function for a coordinate infinitesimal transformation (Poincaré group)
For a coordinate infinitesimal transformation of the form $x^{\prime \mu} = x^{\mu} + a^{\mu} + \omega^{\mu}_{ \ \nu}x^{\nu}$, we want to derive its effect on a space of scalar functions $f(x)$. This requires a Taylor expansion of $f$, which can be written as
\begin{equation*}
f(x^{\prime}) = f(x + a + \omega x) \approx f(x) + a^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}f(x) + \omega^{\mu}_{ \ \nu}x^{\nu}\partial_{\mu}f(x).
\end{equation*}
I have found some questions about this as well, but none that address explicitly how this expansion is carried out. My idea to do this expansion is that $f(x^{\prime})$ is expanded around $x^{\prime}=x$, as it is my understanding of how a Taylor expansion works. Then
\begin{align*}
f(x^{\prime}) \approx& \ f(x) + (x^{\prime} - x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\prime}}f(x) \\
\approx& \ f(x) + (a + \omega x)(1 + \omega)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x) \\
=& \ f(x) + (a + \omega x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x),
\end{align*}
where I used the fact that $x^{\prime} = x + a + \omega x$, and that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\prime}} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial x^{\prime}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = (1 + \omega)\frac{\partial}{\partial x},
\end{equation*}
such that it follows $1 + \omega \approx 1$ as $\omega$ is an infinitesimal parameter. I have done this calculation not for a 4-vector but for a scalar variable. Would this procedure be correct, even for the more general 4-vector case?
